# Bluesnap Forbidden 403 при корректных данных

Tags: rest, платежи

Пытаюсь обновить подписку по урлу https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/subscriptions/:subrcription_id .
В заголовках отправляю

```
Content-Type:application/xml
Authorization:Basic AUTH_KEY
```

где AUTH_KEY получаю сгенерировав в Postman используя API_KEY и API_PASS.

Запрос отправляю методом PUT с телом

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<subscription xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
  <status>A</status>
</subscription>
```

В ответе получаю ошибку

```
Returned when API user does not have the required role (authorization) to perform this operation.
HTTP status code: 403 Forbidden
```

Хотя если меняю статус с активной на отмененную, все проходит успешно

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<subscription xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
  <status>С</status>
</subscription>
```

Втречался ли кто-нибудь с такой ошибкой и как её можно обойти?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается в bluesnap просто временно прикрыли возможность использования API команд, в которых у меня возникли проблемы